# Is Jquery Required for Excel Javascript Development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, ms-office

This article mentions jquery:

https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/build-your-first-excel-add-in?product=excel

Is jquery required for developing Excel Javascript Addins?

thx

Comment: The article is about how to create an add-in for jQuery, so for this example, the answer is yes.

Comment: thx, yes, i understand that the example in that article requires jQuery. My question is whether jQuery is required for ALL addins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is jquery required for developing Excel Javascript Addins?

No, JQuery is not required for any Office add-in development. Please refer to [Anatomy of an Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#anatomy-of-an-office-add-in)